# Replicating `std::thread::spawn` results in stack overflow

Tags: multithreading, rust

## Description

I am trying to spawn threads on my Windows machine in a `#[no_std]` crate, but I am running into problems in the [__chkstk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/-win32-chkstk) function. To start off I created a crate with std and tried to find the places that are responsible for spawning threads in libstd.

## Libstd code (shortened to only show the relevant parts)

```rust
// libstd/thread/mod.rs
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    Builder::new().spawn(f).expect("failed to spawn thread")
}

// libstd/thread/mod.rs
impl Builder {
    pub fn spawn<F, T>(self, f: F) -> io::Result<JoinHandle<T>>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> T,
        F: Send + 'static,
        T: Send + 'static,
    {
        unsafe { self.spawn_unchecked(f) }
    }

    pub unsafe fn spawn_unchecked<'a, F, T>(self, f: F) -> io::Result<JoinHandle<T>>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> T,
        F: Send + 'a,
        T: Send + 'a,
    {
        // ...

        imp::Thread::new(
            mem::transmute::<Box<dyn FnOnce() + 'a>, Box<dyn FnOnce() + 'static>>(Box::new(
                main,
            )),
        )

        // ...
    }
}

// libstd/sys/windows/thread.rs
impl Thread {
    pub unsafe fn new(p: Box<dyn FnOnce()>) -> io::Result<Thread> {
        extern "system" fn thread_start(main: *mut c_void) -> c::DWORD {
            unsafe { start_thread(main as *mut u8); }
            0
        }

        let p = box p;

        let ret = c::CreateThread(
            // ...
            thread_start,
            &*p as *const _ as *mut _,
            // ...
        );

        if ret as usize == 0 {
            Err(io::Error::last_os_error())
        } else {
            mem::forget(p);
            Ok(Thread { handle: Handle::new(ret) })
        };
    }
}

// libstd/sys_common/thread.rs
pub unsafe fn start_thread(main: *mut u8) {
    // ...

    Box::from_raw(main as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce()>)()
}

// libstd/sys/windows/c.rs
extern "system" {
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread
    pub fn CreateThread(
        lpThreadAttributes: LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,
        dwStackSize: SIZE_T,
        lpStartAddress: extern "system" fn(*mut c_void) -> DWORD,
        lpParameter: LPVOID,
        dwCreationFlags: DWORD,
        lpThreadId: LPDWORD,
    ) -> HANDLE;
}
```

## My attempt at replicating libstd

I cut down the code for this example, this is the short, single-threaded way how I tried to replicate libstd:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Handle(usize);

fn spawn_std_like<F, T>(f: F) -> Handle
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    try_spawn_std_like(f).expect("failed to spawn thread")
}

fn try_spawn_std_like<F, T>(f: F) -> Result<Handle, ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    extern "system" fn thread_start(main: *mut u8) -> u32 {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(main as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce()>)(); }
        0
    }

    let p = Box::new(Box::new(f));

    let handle = CreateThread(
        thread_start,
        &*p as *const _ as *mut _
    );

    if handle.0 != 0 {
        core::mem::forget(p);
        Ok(handle)
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

// Minimal version of `kernel32.CreateThread`, with only the relevant parameters.
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
extern "system" fn CreateThread(
    start_address: extern "system" fn(*mut u8) -> u32,
    parameter: *mut u8
) -> Handle {
    start_address(parameter);
    // Emulate successful `CreateThread` call.
    Handle(4)
}
```

Calling this with `spawn_std_like(|| println!("std_like!"));` crashes the process with a stack overflow in `__chkstk` because it uses some memory address instead of the closure size as the "counter" to access memory pages: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7E41FE948 in example.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000EFEDC06000).`

Stack trace:

- `__chkstk()` Line 109 (d:\agent_work\5\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\misc\amd64\chkstk.asm)
- `std::alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(), FnOnce<()>>(core::ops::function::Box<FnOnce<()>> self)` Line 1015 (boxed.rs)
- `std::alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(), alloc::boxed::Box<FnOnce<()>>>(core::ops::function::Box<FnOnce<()>> * self)` Line 1015 (boxed.rs)
- `try_spawn_std_like::thread_start(unsigned char * main)` (main.rs)
- `try_spawn_std_like::<closure-0, ()>(main::closure-0)` (main.rs)
- `spawn_std_like<closure-0, ()>(main::closeure-0 f)` (main.rs)
- `main()` (main.rs)

## Other variants I tried

```rust
// Explicitly typed out, `std` style.
fn spawn0<F, T>(f: F) -> Result<Handle, ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    extern "system" fn thread_start(f: *mut u8) -> u32 {
        let f = f as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce()>;
        let f: Box<Box<dyn FnOnce()>> = unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(f)
        };
        f();
        0
    }

    let p = Box::new(Box::new(f));

    let handle = CreateThread(
        thread_start,
        &*p as *const _ as *mut _
    );

    if handle.0 != 0 {
        core::mem::forget(p);
        Ok(handle)
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

// Explicitly typed out, with `into_raw`.
fn spawn1<F, T>(f: F) -> Result<Handle, ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    extern "system" fn thread_start(f: *mut u8) -> u32 {
        let f = f as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce()>;
        let f: Box<Box<dyn FnOnce()>> = unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(f)
        };
        f();
        0
    }

    let f: Box<Box<F>> = Box::new(Box::new(f));
    let f: *mut Box<F> = Box::into_raw(f);

    let handle = CreateThread(
        thread_start,
        f as *mut _
    );

    if handle.0 != 0 {
        Ok(handle)
    } else {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(f); }
        Err(())
    }
}

// Implicitly typed `spawn1` variant.
fn spawn2<F, T>(f: F) -> Result<Handle, ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    extern "system" fn thread_start(f: *mut u8) -> u32 {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(
                f as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce()>
            )();
        }
        0
    }

    let f = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Box::new(f)));

    let handle = CreateThread(
        thread_start,
        f as *mut _
    );

    if handle.0 != 0 {
        Ok(handle)
    } else {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(f); }
        Err(())
    }
}

// Generic `thread_start` routine.
fn spawn3<F, T>(f: F) -> Result<Handle, ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    extern "system" fn thread_start<F, T>(f: *mut Box<F>) -> Handle
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> T,
        F: Send + 'static,
        T: Send + 'static
    {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(f)(); }

        Handle(1)
    }

    let f = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Box::new(f)));

    let handle = thread_start(f);

    if handle.0 != 0 {
        Ok(handle)
    } else {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(f); }
        Err(())
    }
}

// More explicit type in type-cast in `thread_start`. Does not compile.
/*
fn spawn4<F, T>(f: F) -> Result<Handle, ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    extern "system" fn thread_start(f: *mut u8) -> u32 {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(
                // f as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn Send + 'static) + Send + 'static>
                // f as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce() -> (dyn Sized + Send + 'static) + Send + 'static>
            )();
        }
        0
    }

    let f = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Box::new(f)));

    let handle = CreateThread(
        thread_start,
        f as *mut _
    );

    if handle.0 != 0 {
        Ok(handle)
    } else {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(f); }
        Err(())
    }
}
*/

// Like `spawn2`, but with `+ Send + 'static`.
fn spawn5<F, T>(f: F) -> Result<Handle, ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    // `kernel32.CreateThread` like start routine.
    extern "system" fn thread_start(f: *mut u8) -> u32 {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(
                f as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>
            )();
        }
        0
    }

    let f = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Box::new(f)));

    let handle = CreateThread(
        thread_start,
        f as *mut _
    );

    if handle.0 != 0 {
        Ok(handle)
    } else {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(f); }
        Err(())
    }
}
```

For all versions other than `spawn3` the actual code inside the closure is stripped out of the binary by the compiler, so it can never work. I tried this in my minimal `#[no_std]` crate by calling `user32.MessageBox` in the closure and it does not appear in the imported function list inside the binary. It also crashes in my implementation of `__chkstk`. I can see while debugging that the parameter sent to the function in the `rax` register (special calling convention) contains a memory address instead of the size of the closure, and it decrements the parameter in the loop by 0x1000 each time and touches the stack page until the stack overflows.

## Generic `kernel32.CreateThread`

`spawn3` is the only variant that actually works. But I can not use this for the real `kernel32.CreateThread`, because imported C functions and their parameters can not be generic in Rust (`error[E0044]: foreign items may not have type parameters`):

```rust
#[link(name = "kernel32", kind = "dylib")]
extern "system" {
    fn CreateThread<
        F: Send + 'static + FnOnce() -> T,
        T: Send + 'static
    >(
        security_attributes: *const u8,
        stack_size: usize,
        start_address: extern "system" fn(*mut Box<F>) -> u32,
        parameter: *mut Box<F>,
        attributes: u32,
        id: *mut u32
    ) -> usize;
}
```

I guess it should be possible and I'm just doing something wrong, since it works in libstd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the line

```
let p = Box::new(Box::new(f));
```

you are creating a `Box<Box<F>>`. The two boxes here are thin pointers, because `F` happens to be `Sized` here and because `Box<T>` is always `Sized`.

On the line

```
unsafe { Box::from_raw(main as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce()>)(); }
```

you are trying to interpret the inner `Box` as a `Box<dyn FnOnce()>`. `Box<dyn FnOnce()>` is a fat pointer: a raw pointer coupled with some auxiliary data – in the case of `dyn Trait` types, the auxiliary data is a pointer to the vtable.

In order for your code to work, you need to actually create a `Box<dyn FnOnce()>`. To do this, you need to cast the inner `Box`, like this:

```
let p = Box::new(Box::new(f) as Box<dyn FnOnce()>);
```

Now, this isn't enough; the cast isn't valid because `F` implements `FnOnce() -> T`, not `FnOnce()` (which is a shorthand for `FnOnce() -> ()`). Changing the bound `F: FnOnce() -> T` to `F: FnOnce()` and removing the now redundant `T` on `spawn_std_like` and `try_spawn_std_like` will solve this. Another option is to wrap `f` in a closure that returns `()`:

```
let p = Box::new(Box::new(|| { f(); }) as Box<dyn FnOnce()>);
```

Comment: That works like a charm! I felt like something was wrong with my `Box` types, because the generic `thread_start` routine worked correctly. Good to know that `Box(Sized)` is thin. It then makes sense that I need to box it as a fat `Box` first, in order to use it as a fat `Box`. Thank you!